# How to copy row to another row in a spreadsheet (without deleting) and adding additional information in dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am looking for a way to copy a row in a spreadsheet tab to another row in a spreadsheet tab, without deleting it from the original tab. I've created macros on how to do this, but I can't figure out how not to delete the original line item.

Here is a copy of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XPPr9wJ6SO-NkHHJfds9B0hEMsbeT__ecZhqXtl3j9o/edit?usp=sharing

On tab 'FY23 Prospect Tracker' when Column K is 'Received', I would like the entire row to move to tab 'FY23 Pipeline' at the bottom of the other names. Since the formatting for these tabs is different, I only want it to copy(Column A) First Name and (Column B) Last Name AND set (Column D) Donor Stage automatically to "Current" and the (Column E) Stage to "Committed".

Please let me know if it's possible to both copy and change these columns when new rows are copied over.

Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, can you add your current script in your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Of course. On tab FY23 Prospect Tracker, when Column K is "Received" I would like for the row to be copied to tab FY23 Pipeline at the bottom of the current list. In addition, once this row is copied to this new tab, I would like to change Column D to "Current" and Column E to "Committed" in the row. I will copy the script I tried below but it's not working.

Comment: function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named FY23 Prospect Tracker
  // target sheet of move to named FY23 Pipeline
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "FY23 Prospect Tracker" && r.getColumn() == 9 &&

Comment: r.getValue() == "Received") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("FY23 Pipeline");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}

Comment: Here is a copy of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XPPr9wJ6SO-NkHHJfds9B0hEMsbeT__ecZhqXtl3j9o/edit?usp=sharing. On tab 'FY23 Prospect Tracker', when Column K = Received I would like for the row to be copied to a different tab 'FY23 Pipeline'.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that you have already posted a new question which is the same as this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76783304 And, it seems that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.