# Copying one row of spreadsheet to another tab based on dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to copy a row from one sheet to a new sheet based on the dropdown. [Here is my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XPPr9wJ6SO-NkHHJfds9B0hEMsbeT__ecZhqXtl3j9o/edit#gid=236885257). On **FY23 Prospect Tracker** When a row in Column K is "Received" I would like the first two columns of that row to be copied to **FY23 Pipeline**. I have a script below that I've been trying to use, but it is not working and it seems to pull the entire row and not just Columns A and B. Can someone help me fix it?

```
   function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named FY23 Prospect Tracker
  // target sheet of move to named FY23 Pipeline
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 8 or K
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "FY23 Prospect Tracker" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Received") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("FY23 Pipeline");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "FY23 Prospect Tracker" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value == "Received") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("FY23 Pipeline");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 2).copyTo(trg);  
  }
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: This function requires the triggers event object to populate the e parameter.  Just load and save and then  edit the page in the prescribed manner to get it to run

Comment: Unfortunately the function is still not copying the data over. I realized the correct Column was Column K (11) but even with making this change, I can not get this function to work. Is there anything I need to do on my end to enable this to work other than saving the function?

Comment: Oh my gosh, the issue was with my dropdown! It had an extra space and adding this into the function solved the issue. Thank you so much!